# Choosing CakePHP and concern about future scalability problem

Tags: php, zend-framework, cakephp, scalability

i plan to  build a web service that potentially can grow very large with hundreds of thousand of users. i wonder if building in Cake will present scalability issues down the road?

Thank you very much for your inputs, especially form people who have worked on heavy traffic website built with cake

Comment: According to [this page](http://ajbrown.org/blog/2008/12/22/four-reasons-to-hate-cakephp.html) you should avoid Cake - not only because of the poor scalability.
Besides that, from my personal opinion from working with existing code using Cake, I think using Cake is horrible.

Comment: Go with codeigniter .. Very nice Framework .. much more scalable .

Comment: *LOL* that itself is not really a good reason

Comment: Try searching this site.

Answer (score -1):

For large projects I believe you main concern should be your persistance layer. If it's very large, go with an ORM. That will increase maintainability. For PHP I suggest Doctrine2. That is in Symfony (if I'm not mistaken) and it is also easily compatible with Zend Framework. I suggest those two frameworks, not Cake.

I cannot answer further since I've mainly used ZF and haven't used Cake.